# Creating database table when installing a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I want to create a table into the database upon installing the plugin I've created.

In my main plugin file (index.php):

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wnm_install');

global $wnm_db_version;
$wnm_db_version = "1.0";

function wnm_install(){
global $wpdb;
global $wnm_db_version;
$sql = "CREATE TABLE tbl_campaigns (
campaignID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
campaign_name varchar(128) NOT NULL,
start_duration date NOT NULL,
end_duration date NOT NULL,
activity varchar(500) NOT NULL,
survey_settings varchar(50) NOT NULL,
limit varchar(50) NOT NULL,
goal varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (campaignID)
) ;";

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
dbDelta($sql);
add_option("wnm_db_version", $wnm_db_version);
}
```

I just followed the instructions from this http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

But it doesn't work.

What seems to be the problem with this code?

Comment: Are you getting any error in the error_log? What happens if you execute the query directly in MySQL console?

Comment: there's no error man. it just doesnt work.

Comment: Why is there a semi-colon at the end of the query string??

Comment: i guess that semi-colon is ok. why?

Comment: Semi-colons don't belong in query strings. at least i've never seen them there.

Comment: i did tried to remove the semi colon. but still it doesnt do anything.

Comment: just change the `$sql = ` to `$sql = mysql_query("The string ^ here") or die(mysql_error());` this will tell you why it isn't working. or it will work.

Comment: also get rid of all the wp junk before you execute that (just //comment it out (each line)

Comment: Must have **2 spaces** after PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
limit varchar(50) NOT NULL,
```

Limit is a keyword, change to something else like

```
`limit` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
```

Use back ticks around keywords